# Android different text size depending on screen size

Tags: android

I have two virtual devices, one has 3.7 inch screen (Nexus One, 480x800), the second has 5.5 inch screen (Pixel XL, 1440x2560). I want to use different text size for both devices. I created a few folders: values-small, values-normal, values-large, values-xlarge. Each contains an .xml file with dimension

```
<dimen name="title_text">30dp</dimen>
```

Now I change a value in values-normal directory

```
<dimen name="title_text">40dp</dimen>
```

and expect that it changes the size in Nexus One, but it affects both devices. So how can i distinguish between them ? Changes in values-large and values-xlarge did not affect Pixel XL.

Comment: Instead of using the old `-normal`/`-large`, etc. suffixes, use ones based on dips (e.g., `-sw600dp` for devices whose smallest width is 600dp or greater).

Comment: also: use `sp` unit for font size

Comment: I created values-sw500dp and put there .xml with different size but it has no effect at all on Pixel device. values-sw320dp affects both devices. No idea how to distinguish between them